# Excel - Record cell values, transpose them into columns and copy dynamically changing cells

Tags: excel

English isn't my first language so I hope you will understand me

Beacuse I dont know anything about programming I am turning for help to you: Excel pros;)

I have a workbook with two sheets ( datafeed and record )

On "datafeed", column B, cells B2 to B400 I am capturing live prices from internet.

Currently I use the following :

```
Sub my_onTime()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "my_Procedure"
End Sub

Sub my_Procedure()

With Sheets("record")
    rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 1), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("a2:b2").Value
End With
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    my_onTime
End Sub
```

which currently records prices from "datafeed" to rows in "record".

Another problem is that records only one cell from "datafeed"; cell B2 . I dont know how to set it, so it would record all prices in range from cells B2:B400

My wish is that Excel would record price changes to"record" Sheet into columns not rows.

"Graphic" display what I want:

Sheet1 - "datafeed" ... B2 = 155............Sheet 2 - "record" cells :    F2 = 155.....G2 = 150.....H2 - 145.....I2 - 140,....and so on

Sheet1 - "datafeed" ... B3 = 66.............Sheet 2 - "record" cells :  F3 = 66.....G3 = 67....H3 - 66.....I3 - 65,....and so on

Sheet1 - "datafeed" ... B4 = 1015.............Sheet 2 - "record" cells :  F4 = 1015.....G4 = 1025....H4 - 1035....I4 - 1045,....and so on

Also last recorded price must be put in first column Sheet 2 - "record"; cells: , F2,F3,F4.......(Right now last recorded value is put in last row )

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

p.s

I have added 3 pics for clarification

[1. sheet datafeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79nqz.jpg)

[2. sheet record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaaMr.jpg)

[3. what i wish for sheet record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmBL6.jpg)

Comment: where do the numbers in G3, H3,... in "record" cells come from? At first I thought you want to take the B2:B400 values, transpose them and put them into "record" sheet into F2:OO2 (OO being 400th column from F), but then why would B2 and B3 create separate lines in "record" sheet as you have in your "Graphic" display?

Comment: G3, H3, F3,... values should be previous refreshed prices sorted in columns where 155 is curent price, 150 was 1sec ago, 145 2sec ago,140 3 ago.... This is what I want, because macro from above right now gives me those values in rows and 150 is last the last row.... and so basically useless for me

Answer (score 0):

replace this part of your procedure

```
With Sheets("record")
    rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 1), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("a2:b2").Value
End With
```

with this

```
With Sheets("record")
    rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(rw, 5).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Cells(2, 1).Value 'write name from column A

    iColumn = 6 'set you want to start in column F with prices


    For iRow = Sheets("datafeed").Cells(Sheets("datafeed").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

        .Cells(rw, iColumn).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Cells(iRow, 2).Value

    iColumn = iColumn + 1
    Next iRow

End With
```

if you want the new line added to first line instead of the last

```
With Sheets("record")
    iColumn = 6 'set you want to start in column F with prices
    iRecordRow = 3 'set to what row number to put the current price

    .Rows(iRecordRow & ":" & iRecordRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    For iRow = Sheets("datafeed").Cells(Sheets("datafeed").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        .Cells(iRecordRow, iColumn).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
        iColumn = iColumn + 1
    Next iRow

    .Cells(iRecordRow, 5).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Cells(2, 1).Value 'write name from column A

End With
```

if you want it added to different row than 3 just change number in `iRecordRow = 3`

Comment: @Pavel_V....Thank you for helping me. When I run your macro I get this:...
http://shrani.si/f/41/rl/3Y0Pb03g/first.jpg.... Now it records values from b2: b300 and transposes them, so the first part of the problem is now solved :)
But the second part is still here: It still ads last value of the last row instead of for the first. Would it be possible to do this?...http://shrani.si/f/3R/tn/3SISWWGd/second.jpg

Comment: added into the answer

Comment: @Pavel_V....Thank you for your help so far, you have been very helpful. Now I can move data around on "record" sheet. But now I am facing another problem. I would like to calculate difference between current price and price from X seconds ago. But I can't copy values to make the calculation. Here is what happens: .... shrani.si/f/3A/12d/3EqJuiJU/izracun.jpg..... Once again thank you for all your help and patience with me :)

Comment: you can use function OFFSET to make sure your caculation target cell doesnt move. =OFFSET(F10;2;0) will target F12 and as long as you add rows after row 10 the target of the function will always stay F12

Comment: I still have a problem with calculations. Here is what is happening:.....shrani.si/f/x/EI/1n8hIcsQ/problem.jpg....Thank you

Comment: Read on how OFFSET works - the first cell reference must be above the row that you push down when you insert another row and then the OFFSET number of rows must be chosen appropriately. You cant use OFFSET(I18;2;0) because I18 will be moved when you add a row. So you need to use I8 for example again but move different number of rows than 2.